# Visual Studio Code for Mac crashes on startup

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio Code crashes on startup. To no avail I have uninstalled and reinstalled the application. The issue persists even after having deleted `%HOME%/Library/Application Support/Code`. I feel like this issue may be due to Code using a file on an external HDD when it was forcibly ejected, but I am not sure.

I get the following error on startup:

[image]

Comment: Please report this as issue through the help menu. We can then work on a solution together :).

Comment: @BenjaminPasero A similar report exists: https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/Detail/16451. I will create one for Mac.

Comment: @BenjaminPasero issue created here: https://code.visualstudio.com/issues/detail/16826

Comment: For others who met similar crashes: you should check OS X crash log (in Console app) to see what exactly is the call stack. That either shows a hint on what might be the cause (when the solution in this thread did not help), or gives you something to report to Visual Studio Code guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by:

1. Following the steps to make the Mac version of Visual Studio Code able to be launched from Terminal: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup
2. Launching Visual Studio Code from Terminal

If it continues to not work, maybe try launching from a different folder.